# TypeError: Cannot read property 'prefix' of undefined

Tags: javascript, next.js, font-awesome

I cannot for the life of me figure out why my Next JS app does not work on first load on mobile on some pages.

This is the error I get:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'prefix' of undefined
at value (e58ad660f61adae3bef60024de92d3bccb597bc6.ac485a8c6af9f1bd0a28.js:1)
at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
at n.value (e58ad660f61adae3bef60024de92d3bccb597bc6.ac485a8c6af9f1bd0a28.js:1)
at Module.Zisd (my-account-c12932b172283a18c089.js:1)
at l (webpack-50bee04d1dc61f8adf5b.js:1)
at my-account-c12932b172283a18c089.js:1
at 9f9486d2dee4d90f1a0c817d9cd505415df353ca.95446c2205ebcde0dc47.js:1
```

Sorry if that is garbage but it's all I've got.
I'm using Fortawesome and found [this thread](https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/issues/12966) but I am using and importing the icons correctly.
The thing is I try and use a page link to go to the page and it hard errors. Then I just hit refresh and it works again. What would make it behave like that?

Any ideas how to fix or even how I can better debug this issue?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So turns out my build still references old fontawesome icons.

I removed 2 icons from this code....cause i wasn't using them anymore, but turns out they are still referenced somewhere obscure (Not in my code). So for now they will live in the code doing nothing but stopping an error.

```
import {
  faList,
  faCogs,
  faArrowCircleRight,
  faArrowCircleLeft,
} from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'
library.add(faList)
library.add(faCogs)
library.add(faArrowCircleRight)
library.add(faArrowCircleLeft)
```